# Why cant i define a constant and than use it in a function in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, constants

```
    element ::Int->Int->[[Int]]-> Int
    element z s m= m!!z!!s
    maxIndex :: Int
    maxIndex = 6  

    matrix :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    matrix a row column maxIndex = if maxIndex < length a then error "Out of range"
         else if (row-1<0 || row-1>maxIndex)||(column-1<0 || column-1>maxIndex) then error "Out of range"
         else element (row-1) (column-1) a
```

Where do i make the mistake? i want that my program take my maxIndex constant so the user shouldnt have to enter a value for maxIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxIndex` is already a defined identifier in the lexical scope of matrix. Just like element, you don't need to do anything special to use it, so you can just say:

```
matrix :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int
matrix a row column = ...
```

Comment: No, `maxIndex` is not a function. The rest is still correct, though.

Comment: @kosmikus: it's not really a function in the mathematical sense, but i thought that from the perspective of haskell, there isn't that much of a difference between things like `maxIndex` and "real" functions. Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: A function is something of type `A -> B` (for suitable types `A` and `B`). Functions can be applied to an argument in order to produce a result. An `Int` is not a function.

Comment: @kosmikus: by that definition `readLn` isn't a function either. But what do you call it if not a function. It's certainly not a constant.

Comment: @tauli It is a constant in a way. It's an IO-action that when executed reads a line of input from stdin, calls the appropriate `read` function to convert the input to a value of the requested type, and returns the result of the conversion (or fails, if stdin is corrupted, the input isn't a suitable argument for `read`, ...). In another way, it is a function, because under the hood, the `read` function is passed as an argument to `readLn`.

Comment: Before we rehash all the old arguments, it is perhaps a good time to point at http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell again.

Comment: If one wants to be deliberately obtuse, it's possible to argue that polymorphic values are implicitly functions whose first argument is a type... :]

Comment: @kosmikus: thank you for that link. i found the article quite helpful.